# When should I end a C++ program with 'return 0'?

Tags: c++, return, program-entry-point

I am new to C++ and I'm reading a book called Big C++. In the book, all of the example programs I've seen so far end with `return 0;` before the final `}`. I can apparently make C++ programs run without `return 0;` at the end, so I'm wondering what purpose it serves. I am familiar with returning something from a method in java, but I don't understand why `int main()` would need to return 0 in C++. To get more to the point: Should I always end my `main()` with `return 0;` in C++? If not, when do I need to and when shouldn't I? What is `return 0;` telling the program to do?

In a related question, I am assuming that the main() in C++ is setting up the main function like the main method in java. Is that correct? Why is the main method being declared as an integer? Is that what is happening in the line `int main() {`?

Comment: You should stick to one question at a time.

Comment: I edited your question to remove the second question. You should post it as a separate question. If you feel my edit was unjustified, you can roll back my edits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

that represents [exit code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) of application ,

For example if you launch it via some scripts and they want to determine if the program terminated normally exit code should be `0`, non zero means some type of errors

speaking of Java

if you have specified `int` as return type you must have to return otherwise it won't compile, in case of void type it is zero unless there is an exception thrown out of jvm

Comment: And no return statement means an imlicit `return 0;` (in `main` only)

Comment: if you have specified `int` as return type you must have to return otherwise it won't compile, in case of `void` type it is zero unless there is an exception thrown out of jvm

Comment: No, there is an exception for `main` (note the question is tagged C++)

Comment: it was tagged under Java before

Answer (score 7):

In principle, any function returning something different than `void` has to be exited using a `return` statement (unless an exception is thrown): falling off the end of a function returning something else than `void` results in undefined behavior.

The beauty of C++ is that there are many exception to general rules: you can fall off the end of `main()` which behaves identical to using `return EXIT_SUCCESS;` which in turn is identical to `return 0;`. The reason for this special rule is something from the distant history of C and C++ as far as I understand (although I don't have any statement I could quote on this). In summary, although you don't need to return anything from `main()` using a suitable return statement is more consistent. I tend to omit it when putting code on slides for presentations but in real programs I always include a return statement.

BTW, if you want to indicate that a C++ program failed, you should probably return `EXIT_FAILURE` which is aside from `EXIT_SUCCESS` the only other value guaranteed to work. In practice other return codes also work but there isn't any guarantee.

Comment: There is an explanation from the creator of C++: http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#void-main

Comment: @enedil: note that Bjarne's explanation does _not_ explain why the `return` statement can be omitted! The implicit `int` rule is not a sufficient reason as the return type could be omitted everywhere an `int` was returned but all other functions still required a `return` statement.

Answer (score 4):

In case of C++, `return 0;` is implied. That is:

```
int main()
{
}
```

is equal to

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `main` which serves as an entry point for your app is the only one that allows you to omit the `return` statement for non-void return type.

Apart from that, the value itself is used to inform any other process (e.g. parental process) about the execution result, e.g. by reading it through posix `waitpid`.

Answer (score 1):

The main method is being declared as an integer, because you'd want it to return one. If the main method returns 0, it basically means everything went alright.